# Type of Header for Motherboard PWR Switch

Tags: microcontroller, switches, atx, header, motherboard

I am trying to make my own 2-position connector cable to connect a Rasberry to the `PWR_SW`'s `PWR` and `GND` pins on the motherboard system panel headers, as shown in the diagram below.

Can you identify the type of connector? Also attached a photo of how it looks like.

If it's simply known as a connector, how should I filter down to this type of connector on Digikey?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Everyone has these at home, nobody ever buys that. Therefore you never need to know the name. It's "Hey, give me that wire - no, the other one".

Comment: I was searching for IDC cables and got no where. Stackexchange is uber awesome

Comment: That's because IDC are Insulation Displacing. These are not that type of connectors.

Comment: This is the same kind of header that's on your Raspberry Pi as the GPIO header, what are you using to connect to that?

Comment: @immibis I'm creating a Raspberry pi shield that has headers to plug these DuPont cables into

Answer (score 10):

This should be a standard 0.1" (2.54 mm) pitched header.

A name of that thing goes along the lines of SIL (single in line) female crimp housing (for the part which goes on the cable) with fitting crimp contacts for the cable.

Something like [this](https://www.digikey.de/product-detail/de/harwin-inc/M20-1060200/952-2227-ND/3728191) and [this](https://www.digikey.de/product-detail/de/harwin-inc/M20-1180042/952-2158-ND/3728124).

[image: housing][image: crimp contact]

There are certainly some already confectioned cables out there (like in the picture you posted). I'm not so good at finding cables, but I'd go with the keywords: 0.1" 2 pin cable, and see what I'm getting.

Looking around a bit, a good name for a cable seems to be: 2 pin jumper cable

Probably because jumpers are just the same 0.1" pitched header.

Comment: Here's a cable version with 1 connector: https://www.digikey.de/product-detail/de/sparkfun-electronics/PRT-08672/PRT-08672-ND/7393697

Comment: Or with 2 connectors: https://www.digikey.de/product-detail/de/sparkfun-electronics/PRT-08614/PRT-08614-ND/7393694

Comment: Thank you! Also, is there a crimping tool needed to connect thte crimp contacts to a stripped end of a wire? Or do you simply press those tabs down to hold on to the wire? @ThomasWeller

Comment: Still searching for a suitable AWG for the cable to fit into the crimp contacts

Comment: @Nyxynyx, you can just solder a wire to these contacts, and cut the excess of metal. AWG22 to AWG28 is typical for those.

Answer (score 7):

A popular trade name or search terms got these are **Dupont connectors.** Even when not made by DuPont. Universal connectors for standard 0.1" headers.

[image]

Otherwise they can be found as female to male or female **jumper wire**. These will often be 1x1 single connectors. Which are used as often as dual connector for what you want. Preassembled to various lengths, instead of needing to crimp (which requires the right size wire, the parts, and a good crimping tool).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that damn near every connector manufacturer makes the things but every connector manufacturer has a different name for them. You will find the term "Dupont connector" is used by the direct from china sellers on the likes of Ebay but you won't find it in a serious supplier catalogue.

What I tend to find works best is to go into the "wire to board connectors" section of the suppliers site, select the pin count and pin pitch (2.54mm), sort by price and then look at the pictures until I find what I want.

Answer (score 3):

Other answers note that these are most often colloquially called "DuPont Connectors" but if you want the name of the actual connector series, it's "Mini-PV."  This series was originally produced by DuPont, but they have long since exited the connector market entirely.  The rights to the name passed along to several other companies through mergers and buyouts, but today you can still buy "official" [Mini-PV connectors from Amphenol-ICC](https://www.digikey.com/catalog/en/partgroup/mini-pv-basics-series/8377).  They are very expensive.

The connectors you get on eBay/AliExpress are almost always cheap unbranded knockoffs of Mini-PV, but if you want something available from reputable sellers that's somewhere in-between, [Harwin M20](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/result?s=N4IgjCBcoLQCxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDa4ADABxgUgC6hADgC5QggC%2B3QA) is a series with the same form factor, but a simplified and cheaper design.

[This blog post](http://www.mattmillman.com/info/crimpconnectors/dupont-and-dupont-connectors/) by Matt Millman has a bunch more information about these types of connectors, and in particular which crimping tools work best.

Comment: +1 for finally answering the question of why theses are called "dupont connectors", a term that prior to your answer I had only associated with ebay/aliexpress sellers.